# How can i execute a python script using java?

Tags: python, java, execution

I'm trying to integrate a python script in java. I want my java program to be able to execute my python script

I tried to code a class named PythonCaller made to execute a test python script

```
package pythontest;

import java.io.*;
public class PythonCaller {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // set up the command and parameter
            String pythonScriptPath = "D:\\Programmes\\test.py";
            String[] cmd = new String[2];
            cmd[0] = "D:\\Programmes\\python.exe"; // check version of installed python: python -V
            cmd[1] = pythonScriptPath;
             
            // create runtime to execute external command
    
            Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python D:/Documents/Télécom/Programmation/workspace python/test.py");
            System.out.println("adhi");
            // retrieve output from python script
            BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
            System.out.println(bfr.readLine());
            String line = "";
            try {
                while((line = bfr.readLine()) != null) {

            // display each output line form python script
            System.out.println(line);
            System.out.println("daiuh");
            }
            }
                catch(IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Exception in reading output" + e.toString());
                }
            
    }
    }
```

When i execute it, it appears that bfr.readLine() returns null

Here is the script in test.py :

```
print("aiujadh")
print("f")
```

what i dont understand is that i did tests with the exact same code before, and it worked. I changed it because it failed to read the lines that were not "prints". Then i moved back to the working code, and it doesnt work anymore. I looked at similar topics on the internet, and i do not understand why my code doesn't work.
Can somebody try to explain me pls ?

Comment: HINT: `cmd` is an array. You are currently passing **one** (**1**) `String` instead of an array. There are simpler ways to invoke (a) python (b) an external process `ProcessBuilder`

Comment: Have you tried to call the Python script directly from command line?

Comment: finally i will not use cmd.

Comment: how can i call the python script directly from command line ?